# redirect any subdomain to main domain with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm attempting to redirect any direct attempts to access `sub.example.com/login` over to the original domain/uri at `example.com/login`, and from the number of questions I've already read in regards to this exact thing, it would appear easy on the surface of it...

I don't know if there's something going on that's overriding the desired outcome, but I have the following rules in my **.htaccess** file, yet I'm still able to access `sub.example.com/login` without being redirected.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com/login$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/login$1        [L,R=301]
```

---

Actually, just for complete clarity, here's my entire **.htaccess** file contents. Maybe somebody else can see something wrong that I'm missing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# redirect subdomain login attempts to main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com/login$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/login$1        [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I guess I should also mention, I've tried every variation on the location of this particular cond/rule combo... I've placed it at the very top, directly beneath `RewriteEngine On`, and where it's at now... The very bottom.

Comment: What do the debug logs for the rewrite module say ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2, [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4) ?

Comment: I've looked through all the logs I can find, and I don't see any mentions of redirects or rewrites... Is mod_rewrite logging enabled by default, or do I need to do something to enabled it?

Comment: Follow the links in my previous comment : you need to activate them (`RewriteLogLevel 3` or `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3`).

Answer (score 1):

Put Redirect subdomain login rewrite condition & rule just after RewriteBase line. That should help to address your issue.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do the trick, either... Does the pattern in the rewrite rule look correct? If so, then I'm of the inclination that there must be something else somewhere else that's overriding it... Not sure where, as this is the only **.htaccess** file I can find...

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com$ [NC]                                     
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [L,R=301]                                                                                                       This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect all subdomains to example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
# Redirect only bar & foo subdomains to example.com
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(bar|foo)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [L,R]
```